# WooCommerce: Show notice on new order email if specific payment method is used

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to add a notice to "new order" email sent to admins before the table so if customer paid with "Purchase Order", processing team will know the payment is pending.

**Research & Work Done:**
I spent some time researching various tuts and docs and came up with the **Version 1** code but it's not showing anything on the order email (I changed the code **Version 2** and tried again but to no avail). Are the codes wrong? I just want to confirm before I look into other options. Thank you

**Version 1**

```
/* Payment pending instruction if payment method is "Purchase Order" */
function add_order_instruction_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if ( $sent_to_admin ) {
        echo '<p><strong>Payment Method:</strong> '.$order->payment_method_title().'</p>';
        if ( 'Purchase Order' == $order->get_payment_method_title() ) {
            /* if purchase order method is used */
            echo '<p><strong>Note:</strong> Payment is pending, please contact customer for payment before processing order for shipping.</p>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_email_order_table', 'add_order_instruction_email', 20, 4 );
```

**Version 2**

```
/* Payment pending instruction if payment method is "Purchase Order" */
function add_order_instruction_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if ( $email->id == 'new_order' ) {
        echo '<p><strong>Payment Method:</strong> '.$order->payment_method_title().'</p>';
        if ( 'Purchase Order' == $order->get_payment_method_title() ) {
            /* if purchase order method is used */
            echo '<p><strong>Note:</strong> Payment is pending, please contact customer for payment before processing order for shipping.</p>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_email_order_table', 'add_order_instruction_email', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: What version of woocommerce are you using? Is this action even called? I didn't find it on [woocommerce's hook reference](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html).

Comment: okay I made a mistake in this post it's get_payment_method_title() (post now updated) ..using latest WC version. You can find it here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html and https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/

Comment: What about the action? I'm talking about `woocommerce_before_email_order_table`

Comment: oops...you are right! I have fixed the code, it's working now. Thanks @GuilhermePressutto

Answer (score 1):

If someone else is interested in this, here's what worked for me:

```
/* Payment pending instruction if payment method is "Purchase Order" */
function add_order_instruction_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if ( $email->id == 'new_order' ) {
        if ( 'Purchase Order' == $order->get_payment_method_title() ) {
            echo '<p><strong>Note:</strong> Payment is pending, please contact customer for payment before processing order for shipping.</p>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'add_order_instruction_email', 10, 4 );
```