# Add a text to emails if Woocommerce order item has a specific custom metadata

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, email-notifications

I want to add a notice section to **order emails sent to admin** if specific meta has a specific value (Umbrella Hole is "YES").

Code up till now:

```
function add_order_instruction_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        $target_value = $item->get_meta('Umbrella Hole');
        if ($target_value == "Yes") {
            echo '<div style="background-color:antiquewhite;padding:5px;margin-bottom:10px;"><strong><span style="color:red;">Note:</span></strong> Umbrella Hole is present in the order. Please make sure velcro zipper split is requested from supplier too.</div>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'add_order_instruction_email', 10, 4 );
```

But it's not working. Anything I am doing wrong? Using latest versions of WordPress and WooCommerce.

References:
[Get custom order item metadata in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807333/get-custom-order-item-metadata-in-woocommerce-3)
[How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)
[WooCommerce: Show notice on new order email if specific payment method is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948609/woocommerce-show-notice-on-new-order-email-if-specific-payment-method-is-used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested your code and it works for a registered order item meta data which key is `Umbrella Hole`, see it below on `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` table for a `line_item`:

[image]

> So the problem can only comes from the **order item custom meta data that is not registered**

I have revisited lightly your code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'add_order_instruction_email', 10, 4 );
function add_order_instruction_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        if ( "Yes" == $item->get_meta('Umbrella Hole') ) {
            echo '<div style="background-color:antiquewhite;padding:5px;margin-bottom:10px;"><strong><span style="color:red;">Note:</span></strong> Umbrella Hole is present in the order. Please make sure velcro zipper split is requested from supplier too.</div>';
            $break; // Stop the loop to avoid repetitions
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Here below the email notification when any order line item has a registered meta data `Umbrella Hole` with `"yes"` as value:
>
> [image]

Comment: my code was working too...it turned out to be a cache issue. Your version works too so marking it as accepted answer. Thank you for the explanation

Comment: @DanishMuneer yes I know that your code works as I just say that in the beginning of my answer. For the **cache** issue, nobody can guess that…